# Pandas pd.concat works on first pass but says 'No objects to concat' on subsequent passes

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I have an interesting problem with Python PANDAS leveraging concat.

On the first pass everything works fine on the subsequent passes I receive "No objects to concat". It doesn't make sense because it's looking at the same "CSV's" on each run so in theory there should always be something to "concat"

What I am doing:
I have a function that looks at incoming URL data opens a csv with two columns and pulls the first column where second column matches the URL data.

Example CSV:
  Two columns:
Test   | URL
Test 2 | URL

Code I am using:

```
        path = r'./resources/URL'  # location of CSV's
        allFiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

        list_ = []

        for file_ in allFiles:
            data = pd.read_csv(file_, index_col=None, header=0)
            list_.append(data)

        df = pd.concat(list_, axis=0, ignore_index=True)

        search = df[df['URL'].str.contains(":" + groupid.group(1))]

        df1 = search[['Column1']]

        for index, row in df1.iterrows():
            data = ('{0}'.format(row['Column1']))

        newid = idgrab(data)# Pass data off to another function
```

Any idea what might be going on here? Even if I pass the same data over the function multiple times I receive the same error after the initial run.

Comment: you mean second part of the loop, or the second time you run the entire code?

Comment: The code I have above is actually wrapped in a function. As new URL's are processed they are passed to this function to pull from the CSV's located on disk. The goal is to pull Column A where CSV- URL matches to incoming URL.

Comment: The first URL that goes through and everything works the second URL and thereafter I get 'No Object to concat' and 'list' is empty.

Do I need to clear Panda or something before the second URL comes through?

Comment: I guess I should be more clear on the CSVs. It's only two columns and they match in all the CSV's.

Answer (score 0):

Your list_ is empty which is what is throwing that error. You should look at the csv's in allFiles. Are you moving the csv's or are they getting renamed in the directory?

Comment: Thanks Tyler for responding and my apologies for the delay.

I thought the same thing...actually if I debug it shows that it's empty on the second, third...etc iteration. The .csv's are unchanged while the process is running which is what's so confusing. 

It's just a simple loop and should contain data on not only the first iteration but thereafter...correct?

Comment: My only other guess would be that your path gets changed somehow and so cannot find the csv's on disk.